# How can I get to access to the attrribute of my foreign key in my model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hello I am using Django and in my project I define a class which contains a foreign key. My problem is the following one :

I don't achieve to access to the attributes of the field which is defined by  the foreign key.

Basically I tried this :

```
    mytable = MyTable.objects.filter(a=a)
    mytable.a.food
```

So actually mytable contains a foreign field which is defined such as :

```
a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

and in the table a there exist a field by the name of food

But the problem is I get this error :

```
'Queryset' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Could you help me please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to access the model instead of queryset.
For instance:

```
mytable = MyTable.objects.filter(a=a).first()
mytable.a.food
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to get only the attribute food for the first entry but for all the entries that's my problem... Using filter it is not possible to do this ?

Comment: Just iterate the queryset and do whatever you need. Like this: `for model in mytable:  print(model.a.food)`

Comment: Yes but is there a faster method instead of using a loop for ?

Comment: @brucePeter you can use `.values('a__food')` or `.values_list('a__food')` if you need to return only specific fields. They will return dict/list instead of models. It would be a "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table" in the database.

Comment: You might want annotation, or filtering via a relation i.e. `.filter(a__food__startswith="b")` will return all `MyTable` objects whose related `a` object has a `food` field that starts with "b"`. It's not entirely clear to me what you are asking.